# Buffered Writer and Reader Proper order/use

Tags: java, logic, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

So I'm not sure where my mistake is in the order/use of BufferedWriter and BufferedReader. See for yourself.
My program works all except for these methods. Here is where I declared stuff, pretty sure error is not here.

```
        fw = new FileWriter(file, true); 
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Now here is the method that adds thing to the file, pretty sure this one works:

```
public static void addStuff(String toAdd){
    f.format("%s ", toAdd);
    try {
        bw.write(toAdd);
    } catch (IOException e) {               
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error at addstuff");
    }
    System.out.printf("%s added", toAdd);
    System.out.println();
}
```

And last but not least, the method I'm pretty sure I'm doing wrong. This one reads the file that was just added to.

```
public List<String> readFile(){ //return a list off stuff
    try{
        String line = br.readLine();
        stuff.add(line);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Error at readFile");
    }
    return stuff;
}
```

The error I am encountering is that when the file is read by the readFile() method 'null' is printed out, so the program is either not reading correctly or writing correctly.
Like a so:

```
hi added
null
```

Thanks so much in advance, love the java programming community here.

Comment: What about it is not working?

Comment: I am pretty sure your question is not clear. Please explain what is the error you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readLine()` can return null, which means end of stream: in this case, end of file. Your code doesn't allow for that possibility, and it also doesn't allow reporting that possibility to the caller when it happens.

I would get rid of the `readFile()` method altogether, and in its place call `readLine(),` test the result for null, close the file and cease reading if so, otherwise add the line to the collection.

Your exception handling and logging are very poor as well. You are consistently catching exceptions, logging them, and then proceeding as though they hadn't happened. In  `readFile(),` for example, you are logging success even after a failure. Code that depends on the success of code in a try block should be inside that same try block.

Comment: Yeah, now that I read it through my readFile() method is pretty... well... retarded. Thanks for the help!